# 2D object giving a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I'm having a bit of a problem when running the code below. This code is used when a button on a gui screen is pressed. Basically the function of this button is to read text entered into 2 text fields, derive a third value from the 2, and save all 3 in a row in a table on the GUI screen, using a 2d array.

However, i get a NullPointerException when executing it at the 5th line inside the method addItem().
saleData is the 2D array with data which is in the table.
i have instantiated the temp[][] object with 1 row more than the saleData object because i need to add a row to the table, and then i make saleData=temp.
This code worked as it is in the Gui class before i tried using OOP to create a separate class for the GUI to work from. 
The nullpointer exception refers to the temp object, i know this because i printed out the value of temp and it was a null.

Does anyone have any ideas?
thanks in advance.

```
public void addItem() {
    int len = saleData.length + 1;
    Object[][] temp = new Object[len][3];
    for (int k = 0; k < saleData.length; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            temp[k][i] = ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getValueAt(k, i);
        }
    }
    tblContainer.removeComponent(table);
    try {
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText());
        String item = (String) items.getSelectedItem();
        String sql = "Select Sell_price from stockInfo where parts like '" + item + "'";
        double total = 0;
        if (saleData.length != 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < saleData.length; i++) {
                String sql2 = "Select sell_price from stockinfo where parts like '" + temp[i][1].toString() + "'";
                try {
                    System.out.println("Check 0");
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                    System.out.println("Check 1");
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    System.out.println("Check 2");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("Check 3");
                        String qt = temp[i][0].toString();
                        temp[i][2] = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("sell_price")) * Integer.parseInt(qt);
                        System.out.println("Check 4");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Dialog.show("Error", "Error 1: " + e, "OK", null);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                double price = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("Sell_Price"));
                total = qty * price;
                try {
                    for (int m = 0; m < saleData.length; m++) {
                        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).setValueAt(m, n, temp[m][n]);
                        }
                    }
                    temp[saleData.length][0] = qty;
                    temp[saleData.length][1] = item;
                    temp[saleData.length][2] = total;
                    saleData = temp;
                    table = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(saleColumns, saleData, true));
                    tblContainer.addComponent(table);
                    ((TableLayout) table.getLayout()).setGrowHorizontally(true);
                    saleForm.revalidate();

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Dialog.show("Error", "SQL Error Record Sale", "OK", null);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Dialog.show("Error", "Please enter a valid quantity", "OK", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temp array can not be null. You just created it.

`temp[k][i]` *can* be null (and should be, by the way), but that does not matter - it is being assigned a value.

If a dimension of `temp` would not be big enough, you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

So this leaves for two things that can get to be null (if the error stems from that line, and not for example from the inside of `getValueAt(k,i)` ):

- `table`
- `table.getModel()`

Use a debugger, and it will make your life easier...